# Can't compare moment dates in MongoDb

Tags: javascript, mongodb, date, mongoose, momentjs

So my goal is to retrieve posts with comments that are placed today with Mongoose.

**First, I create a start-of-the-day UTC current date object with:**

```
const todayForEvent = moment().startOf('day')
  .utc().toDate();
```

this results in `2019-01-02T06:00:00.000Z`

**then I want to create a DB search with mongoose to fetch the posts where a comment has been placed today**

```
const posts = await Post.find({
        // From this user...
        $and: [
          // Find normal posts that has comments (recent interactions)
          { _posted_by: userId },
          { comments: { $exists: true, $ne: [] } },
          { 'comments.created_date': { $gte: todayForEvent } }
    ]

})
```

**Third, I have mongoose comment documents that have a property created_date**

```
const CommentSchema = new Schema({

  created_date: {
    type: Date,
    default: moment().utc().toDate()
  }

});

const Comment = mongoose.model('Comment', CommentSchema);

module.exports = Comment;
```

**This is the result document after placing a comment**

[image]

**Everything looks OK but for some reason the posts array is still empty after the database search, can someone please tell me what I did wrong**

**EDIT: added post schema at request**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const { Schema } = mongoose;

const PostSchema = new Schema({
  content: {
    type: String,
    trim: true
  },
  _content_mentions: [{
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'User'
  }],
  type: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    enum: ['normal', 'event', 'task']
  },
  _liked_by: [{
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'User'
  }],
  comments_count: {
    type: Number,
    default: 0
  },
  comments: [{
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Comment'
  }],
  _group: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Group',
    required: true
  },
  _posted_by: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'User',
    required: true
  },
  task: {
    due_to: {
      type: String,
      default: null
    },
    _assigned_to: {
      type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: 'User'
    },
    status: {
      type: String,
      enum: ['to do', 'in progress', 'done']
    }
  },
  event: {
    due_to: {
      type: Date,
      default: null
    },
    _assigned_to: [{
      type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: 'User'
    }]
  },
  created_date: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now
  },
  files: [{
    orignal_name: {
      type: String,
      default: null
    },
    modified_name: {
      type: String,
      default: null
    }
  }]
});

const Post = mongoose.model('Post', PostSchema);

module.exports = Post;
```

**EDIT 2: sample post document**

```
{ _id: 5c2d14c30176ac30204809a8,
    task: { due_to: null },
    event: { due_to: null, _assigned_to: [] },
    _content_mentions: [],
    _liked_by: [],
    comments_count: 1,
    comments: [ 5c2d14dc0176ac30204809ab ],
    content: '<p>poging 5 duust</p>',
    type: 'normal',
    _posted_by:
     { _id: 5c292e0e63deb43d9434f664,
       profile_pic: 'default_user.png',
       first_name: 'Jaspet',
       last_name: 'Houthoofd' },
    _group: 5c292db763deb43d9434f660,
    created_date: 2019-01-02T19:45:07.710Z,
    files: [],
    __v: 0,
    liked_by: [] }
```

**EDIT 3: sample comment **

```
{ _content_mentions: [],
  created_date: 2019-01-02T21:10:04.456Z,
  _id: 5c2d28c251f2bd332cdeaf0a,
  content: '<p>hehe</p>',
  _commented_by: 5c292db763deb43d9434f65f,
  _post: 5c2d1dd254ca0429b470f000,
  __v: 0 }
```

Comment: Please don't use bold, and certainly not bold + capitals. Also, not everyone can see images, post text instead.

Comment: Could you paste `Post` schema and sample documents from that collection (code preferred rather than screenshots - easier to reproduce) ? Thanks

Comment: Hey Mickl, I've added it to the original post

Comment: You mean samples form post or comment collection?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So the problem here is that you have two collections, `posts` and `comments`. Based on your `Posts` schema, `comments` array contains only ids that reference documents that are stored in second collection. That's why you can check whether that array exists and is not empty but you can't refer directly to these elements.

To fix that you can use [$lookup](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) to get those documents from `comments` into `posts` and then you can apply your date condition inside [$match](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/index.html), try:

```
let posts = await Post.aggregate([
    { $match: { comments: { $exists: true, $ne: [] }, _postedBy: userId } },
    { $lookup: { from: "comments", localField: "comments", foreignField: "_id", as: "comments" } },
    { $match: { 'comments.created_date': { $gte: todayForEvent } } }
])
```

Comment: You're an absolute god Mickl. thank you so much. I've been stuck on this the entire day